# Read File as Array From SD Card in cordova (ionic) with cordova-plugin-file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I use audio files in my app that I need to get as an buffer array. For this I let the user choose a file ([using Ionic/Cordova FileChooser Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/)) and then I get an URL like:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A8431
```

After that, I sent this to [Cordova Plugin File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) `resolveNativePath` function and I get a Path Like:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Prueba interno/Interno, Teddybär, Dreh Dich Um__320kbps.mp3
```

Here I make my `audioFileInfo` Object

```
audioFileInfo = {name: "Interno, Teddybär, Dreh Dich Um__320kbps.mp3",
                 originalPath: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A8431",
                  path: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Prueba interno"}
```

and finally I call `filePlugin.readAsArrayBuffer(audioFileInfo.path, audioFileInfo.name)` to get the buffer array.

It works ok when the file is in the device internal storage, but when the file comes from the SDCard it does not work because the `readAsArrayBuffer` returns "not found".

**SD Card:**

**File Chooser URL**

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3D91-1C14%3AM%C3%BAsica%20Dana%2F1%20-%20Teddyb%C3%A4r%2C%20Teddyb%C3%A4r%2C%20Dreh%20Dich%20Um__320kbps.mp3
```

**resolveNativePath:**

```
file:///sdcard/Música Dana/1 - Teddybär, Teddybär, Dreh Dich Um__320kbps.mp3
```

**audioFileInfo:**

```
audioFileInfo = {
    name :"1 - Teddybär, Teddybär, Dreh Dich Um__320kbps.mp3"
    originalPath : "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3D91-1C14%3AM%C3%BAsica%20Dana%2F1%20-%20Teddyb%C3%A4r%2C%20Teddyb%C3%A4r%2C%20Dreh%20Dich%20Um__320kbps.mp3",
    path : "file:///sdcard/Música Dana"
}
```

**readAsArrayBuffer:**

```
FileError {code: 1, message: "NOT_FOUND_ERR"}
```

I have tried FilePlugins's `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl()` and I get this `Entry` object:

```
{
    filesystem: {
        name: "content",
        root: {
            filesystem {
                name: "content",
                root: "...."
            }
        },

        fullPath: "/",
        isDirectory: true,
        isFile: false,
        name: "",
        nativeURL: "content://",
    },
    fullPath: "/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3D91-1C14:Música Dana/1 - Teddybär, Teddybär, Dreh Dich Um__320kbps.mp3",
    isDirectory: false,
    isFile: true,
    name: "1 - Teddybär, Teddybär, Dreh Dich Um__320kbps.mp3",
    nativeURL: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3D91-1C14%3AM%C3%BAsica%20Dana%2F1%20-%20Teddyb%C3%A4r%2C%20Teddyb%C3%A4r%2C%20Dreh%20Dich%20Um__320kbps.mp3",
}
```

Bue I have no idea what to use as `path` in the first parameter of the `readAsArrayBuffer` function.

If I use `fullPath` and `name` it throws **encoding error**.
If I get just the "path" without the name from `fullPath`, it also throws **encoding error**.

Does anybody had a similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my own FileReader to process the file with the info returned by `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl`, Please be aware that this code uses Typescript

```js
    let entry = await this.filePlugin.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(audioFileInfo.originalPath);
    let fileEntry: FileEntry = entry as FileEntry;
   
    console.log("fileEntry", fileEntry);
   
    let readFilePromise = new Promise < any > (resolve => {
        console.log("getting File from fileEntry");
        // fileEntry.getMetadata(data => {
        //     console.error("metadata", data); 
        // });
        fileEntry.file((file) => {
            console.log("File", file);
            var reader = new FileReader();
   
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                console.log("Successful file read: ", reader.result);
                resolve(reader.result);
            };
   
            reader.onprogress = (progressEvent) => {
   
                let fileUpdateInfo: FileLoadingUpdateInfo = {
                    audioFileInfo: audioFileInfo,
                    total: progressEvent.total,
                    loaded: progressEvent.loaded,
                    percent: parseFloat((progressEvent.loaded * 100 / progressEvent.total).toFixed(2))
                }
                this.updateAudioFileLoadingText$.next(fileUpdateInfo);
            };
            reader.onerror = (e) => {
                console.error("The reader had a problem", e)
                resolve(undefined);
            }
            reader.onabort = (e) => {
                console.error("We aborted...why???", e)
                resolve(undefined);
            }
            console.log("using reader to readAsArrayBuffer ");
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
   
   
        }, (e) => {
            console.error(e)
        });
    });
    let fileBufferArray = await readFilePromise;
    console.log("fileBufferArray", fileBufferArray);
   
    return fileBufferArray;
```