# "SECURITY_ERR" on resolveLocalFileSystemURL in Ionic App when reading a File without user interaction

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am having this problem reading local audio files. My app allow the user to choose an audio file that is later processed using the WebAudioApi.

I get this file using this fork of [Cordova-File-Chooser](https://github.com/distante/cordova-filechooser) plugin and the I get the file using [Cordova-File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) plugin (this process is detailed in my [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51112939/1255819)).

After the user choose a File, I save the info about the path in `localStorage` so 
when he comes back the next time it loads automatically again. Here comes the problem. Using the exact same info I get a `SECURITY_ERR` when calling `filePlugin` `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl()` or `window.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl()` when the user has previously closed the app.

I store this object:

```
{
    name : "The RedRojo Music - 01 - Animal.mp3"
    originalPath : "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A133500"
    path : "file:///storage/emulated/0/Music/The RedRojo Music/The RedRojo Music - Tristezza EP 2014 [MP3]"
}
```

And I use `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(originalPath)`.

This works correctly if the app is not closed (for example using F5 to reload the content to mock a new App start).

Comment: I’m having a similar issue. In my case the user picks files in general. Have you found a soulution?

Comment: Sadly no @tmuechsck, I had to revert it always to the default state when the user starts the app as workaround.